# Утворення прикметників м'якої та твердої групи

Tags: прикметники

Як вживати -ний -ній при творенні прикметників? Я прочитав у правилах, що потрібно дивитись чи звук "н" м'який(-ій - м'який, -ий - твердий)

> До **твердої** групи належать прикметники з основою на твердий приголосний: *дрібний, тихий*
> До **м'якої** групи належать прикметники з основою на м'який приголосний: *літній, безкраїй*

Але тоді утворюється замкнене коло - щоб дізнатись закінчення потрібно знати групу, щоб дізнатись групу потрібно знати закінчення. Як тоді бути?
Завдання одного з минулих ЗНО:

> **Закінчення -ий має прикметник, утворений від слова**:
> А) тепер
> Б) колись
> В) субота
> Г) вечір
> Д) туман

Відповідь очевидна, проте у книзі Олександра Авраменка "Українська мова та література. ЗНО 2020" не все так легко:

> **Закінчення -ий має прикметник, утворений від слова**
> А) природа
> Б) дорога
> В) вечір
> Г) зовні
> Д) завтра

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я не можу в такому випадку щось порекомендувати. Мені здається, такі речі можна остаточно визначити лише за словником.

Адже те, отримав певний прикметник твердий звук [н] наприкінці основи чи м'який звук [н'] наприкінці основи, — це, мені здається, значною мірою просто історична випадковість. Один і той же корінь може мати одночасно два варіанти основи (наприклад, *[дружний](https://sum20ua.com/Entry/index?wordid=25142&page=836)* і *[дружній](https://sum20ua.com/Entry/index?wordid=25143&page=836)*) або ж «хитатися» залежно від діалекту й історичного періоду (наприклад, *[народний](https://sum20ua.com/Entry/index?wordid=56353&page=1796)* у 1910-ті–1930-ті роки було «модно» вимовляти/писати як *народній* — зокрема Українська Народна Республіка тоді писалася як Українська Народня Республіка й у деякі роки *народній (-ня, -нє)* зустрічалося навіть частіше за *народний (-на, -не)*:
[image]
(частоти вживання *народний* і *народній* — [на основі даних із «ГРАК»](http://batchman.parasolcorpus.org/NGyears.html))).

Деякі прикметники, незважаючи на однозначну словарну фіксацію, можуть де-факто вживатися по-різному:

- дорожний:дорожній = [477](http://www.parasolcorpus.org/bonito/run.cgi/first?corpname=grac10&queryselector=lemmarow&lemma=%D0%B4%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9):[17639](http://www.parasolcorpus.org/bonito/run.cgi/first?corpname=grac10&queryselector=lemmarow&lemma=%D0%B4%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%BD%D1%96%D0%B9);
- зворотний:зворотній = [13108](http://www.parasolcorpus.org/bonito/run.cgi/first?corpname=grac10&queryselector=lemmarow&lemma=%D0%B7%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9):[1328](http://www.parasolcorpus.org/bonito/run.cgi/first?corpname=grac10&queryselector=lemmarow&lemma=%D0%B7%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BD%D1%96%D0%B9);
- природний:природній = [62794](http://www.parasolcorpus.org/bonito/run.cgi/first?corpname=grac10&queryselector=lemmarow&lemma=%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9):[1833](http://www.parasolcorpus.org/bonito/run.cgi/first?corpname=grac10&queryselector=lemmarow&lemma=%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D1%96%D0%B9).

(Дані, знов-таки, з «ГРАК». Тобто з одного боку ми бачимо, що словникові форми справді вживаються частіше, але з іншого — альтернативні варіанти в деяких випадках теж не рідкість.)